# Bitcoin not reaching Recipient

Tags: sell-bitcoins

I would like to find out if its possible for a Bitcoin recipient not to receive a payment while on my side(Sender) it shows that the payment was successful? See print screen of payment below, the payment was done more than 36 hours ago.

[image]

Comment: Either the payment went through or it did not. Are you sure that 1Pnw... is the correct address? Did you click the verify on blockchain.info button?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://blockchain.info/address/1PnwbcQPfWwBPayBvvpcVwK6NjuEmubQTB?sort=0 to check if your payment is on it.